# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

I'm getting error while sending signup information to java spring-boot project from angular. I've tried thousands ways to resolve it but all in vain. Can't figure it out whats stopping java project to accept the request.
Error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/bites/service/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here's my java code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            System.out.println("inside filter>>>>");
             HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Authorization");

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I know that angular signup form is sending accurate request with credentials to the java project but on java side request is denying.

Seeking help.

I'm trying my java application to accept request from angular project

Comment: Just for testing. Does Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * work?

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of client code in the question? And, if possible, what is being sent with the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Angular client is sending the signup credentials information to the java project. I'm 100% that angular is accurately sending the credentials but its not accepting on java side.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It returned the same error of cors in console even after adding in project.